# Sending null id with Navigator arguments without getting any error

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm currently working on a project where I add some paper and users get to view them. I'm having a problem with updating the data on Firebase. I'm trying to select the item via sending the id to the input screen but I can't seem to get the id in the input screen and I end up adding a new item.

The edit button:

```
IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit), onPressed:(){

               Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AdminInputScreen.routeName,arguments:selectedPaper.id);
               print(selectedPaper.id);
                  }),
```

and I should get the id here:

```
void didCangeDependencies(){
if(_isInit){
final paperId = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;

if(paperId !=null){

  _editedPaper=
  Provider.of<Papers>(context,listen: true).findById(paperId);

_initValues={

  'title': _editedPaper.title,
'steps': _editedPaper.steps,
'paperDownload': _editedPaper.paperDownload,
'locaitonlink':_editedPaper.locaitonlink,

};
}
}
 _isInit=false;
super.didChangeDependencies();
}
  @override
  void dispose(){
    _stepsFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I don't get any error in the Debug Console. 
Please let me know if you require more code.

Comment: there is no such method in flutter SDK: `didCangeDependencies`

Comment: well actually there's something called didchangedependencies, i learned flutter from a tutor named max and he's working with it online, and the error actually was ( i fee so ashamed saying this) it was a mere typo in my code, a typo that made me feel so stupid.
thank you for your help, and i'm sorry for wasting your time.